# Rails: first_or_create not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My goal for my application is to only show a form page with existing data or a blank form if new. I've accomplished this by using a callback that created a blank record when the user is created.

User model:

```
before_create :build_health_profile
```

However, if for whatever reason a users "health_profile" were to be destroyed or non-existant, it breaks my entire app with:

"undefined method `health_profile' for nil:NilClass"

It was mentioned to me that the "first_or_create" method could solve this by show a new form or finding the existing one, but I can't get it to save the fields. It directs to my root with my save alert like it saved, but nothing gets actually saved.

Controller:

```
class HealthProfilesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @health_profile = current_user.build_health_profile
  end

  def create
    @health_profile = HealthProfile.where(user_id: current_user).first_or_create(health_profile_params)
    if @health_profile.save
      flash[:success] = "Health profile saved."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def health_profile_params
    params.require(:health_profile).permit(
       :age,
       :weight,
       :height,
       :gender
    )
  end
end
```

I've seen where I could use a block for "first_or_create", but no luck getting that to work.

View:

```
<%= link_to "Health Profile", new_health_profile_path %>
```

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :health_profile, dependent: :destroy
end

class HealthProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use [first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) then that calls the `save` method as part of it on the record and tries to save that in the database. If it can't save the record, then the transaction is rolled back. So, you want to use: [first_or_initialize](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize) here which is like `new` and does not save the record in the database immediately. It just loads the data. So, you can call `save` on it in the next line of your code.

So, in your code, where you have:

```
 @health_profile = HealthProfile.where(user_id: current_user).first_or_create(health_profile_params)
```

Here you are not controlling the `save` part, that's already being done by the `first_or_create` method.

So, you actually want to just load the object (NOT save yet) by using `first_or_initialize`:

```
 @health_profile = HealthProfile.where(user_id: current_user).first_or_initialize(health_profile_params)
```

and then, in the next line, you can call the `save` and based on it's return value you can take the decision:

```
if @health_profile.save
  # do stuff if successfully saved health_profile
else
 # otherwise
 render 'new'
end
```

Comment: I changed it to "first_or_initialize" and verified it saved using the console, but when I go to the same link, it clears the record from the database and renders a blank form.

Comment: `if @health_profile.save` if this is true (means your record got saved to db successfully), then according to your code, it should redirect to the root path. Do you have your code on github? If possible, give me clone access and let me know what you exactly want, I will do that and will get back to you. In than case, my github is: `rakibulislam`

Comment: or, try: `@health_profile.save!` instead of: `@health_profile.save`. In that case, if it can't save the `@health_profile`, it will raise an exception which will be useful to debug the issue. Let me know after trying it!

Comment: It's saving each time with the correct user_id and keeps removing the record as soon as I go back to the form. Here is the git repo: https://github.com/eric-price/RecordConsole

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `@health_profile.save`,

You should change `first_or_create` into `first_or_initialize`

`first_or_create` immediately trigger `save`, whereas `first_or_initialize` would just assign the values to a New record or to an already existing record if record exists already

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem of the record resetting itself when going back to the form by adjusting the new action. Thats everyone for the help.

```
def new
  @health_profile = current_user.health_profile || HealthProfile.new
end

def create
   @health_profile = HealthProfile.where(user_id: current_user).first_or_initialize(health_profile_params)
   if @health_profile.save
     flash[:success] = "Health profile saved."
       redirect_to root_path
   else
       render 'new'
   end
end
```